# Understanding Spatial Locality and Temporal Locality

Tags: c, caching, memory

In this exercise, we look at memory locality properties of matrix computation. The following code is written in C, where elements within the same row are stored contiguously. Assume each word is a 32-bit integer.

```
int i,j,temp;
for (i=0; i<length; i++)
{
    for ( j = 0; j < length - i - 1; j++)
    {
        if (a[ j + 1 ] < a[j])
        {
            temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a [j + 1];
            a[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

}

References to which variables exhibit temporal locality?
References to which variables exhibit spatial locality?

Comment: Spatial locality means close in memory, like in `a[j] = a [j + 1];`. Temporal locality is close in time - perhaps the two uses of the `temp` variable?.

Comment: In this type of question we have to say for example, i,j, and length are examples of temporal locality and a[j+1] is spatial locality. However, I'm not sure about which variables are spatial locality or temporal locality.